# Cassandra Rainbird

Tags: cassandra, real-time, analytics, complex-event-processing

Does anybody know if the rainbird project for aggregations in cassandra has been committed in the main project?

Does anybody have advice about real-time analytic choices? I was thinking of S4 also for CEP type functionality.

Regards.
Tom

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Rainbird was never opensourced.  I wrote a very basic opensource implementation that I used to tutorials (my-first-cassandra-app type thing):

- https://github.com/acunu/painbird

A video of one of the tutorial can be found here:

- http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/tutorial-2-cassandra

(WARNING, PLUG!) My company, Acunu, has built a flexible, realtime analytics platform on top of Cassandra we call Acunu Analytics.  Its like rainbird, but much more flexible, covers more analytics functions (top-k, count distinct) and should be more familiar to people coming from an SQL background.  It is not free, I'm afraid, but a trail version can be downloaded off our website (www.acunu.com).  For more information, see:

- http://www.acunu.com/2/post/2012/09/understanding-realtime-analytics.html
- http://www.acunu.com/2/post/2012/10/acunu-analytics-greater-than-10x-performance-vs-mysql.html
- http://www.acunu.com/2/post/2012/08/announcing-acunu-reflex-with-analytics-v3.html
- http://www.acunu.com/2/post/2012/07/approximate-analytics.html
- http://www.acunu.com/uploads/1/1/5/5/11559475/acunu_reflex_with_analytics_datasheet.pdf

We've also got some cool dashboarding features that we are about to release, built on Acunu Analytics.

Thanks

Tom